# What is sh process in mac and how to kill it

Tags: process, kill

when i give ps -ax command i find number of processes with name "sh". parent of all these sh process is same that is some other process. I am not able to kill sh processes with any of kill commands say kill -9 pid, but in order to kill these sh processes i need to kill parent process.

Comment: please let me know why it is down voted. So that i can rectify...

Comment: This is not a programming question, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sh processes are due to unclosed file discriptors in a process. Due to this multiple sh child processes will be created for main parent process. So in main process we closed all these descriptors. This resolved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `killall sh` or `killall -9 sh`?

Hope this helps

Comment: why not?  if you want to kill all the sh processes, I don't know if there is any better and faster way.  Did you find any problem with that command?

Comment: The issue is all sh processes are having same same parent process. Thats the reason we cant kill child processes here. I figured out the issue. It is due to the file descriptors opened in parent process are the reason for this numerous sh processes. I closed them and issue resolved